# Cluster columns chart in ASP.Net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, charts

I want a cluster column chart in asp.net with C#... I have a table like

See this below reference Figure-6. I want like that chart to do in Asp.net with C#.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27251/Create-Column-Charts-Using-OWC11#_rating

In this link have one problem because they are using Microsoft Excel DLL so I want that chart without using that DLL....ASAP Reply me I want code in C# with out using Microsoft Excel that's amin one...

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Did you try Microsoft Chart Controls (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use highcharts control. There is a lot of different kinds of charts.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Ms Chart Controls - [Samples Environments for Microsoft Chart Controls](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61/view/SamplePack#content)
It seems that the code project article has exactly used the same MS charts.

The sample includes all kind of charts for yoru need.